# Can you export packaging information (ERD or other data model) from Cognos 8.3?

Tags: database, export, package, cognos, erd

I was wondering if there's a way to export package information from Cognos 8 from a regular user level or from the framework level.

For instance, I want the field names that cognos is pointing to on the database, i want the datatype, the description cognos uses when you right click a data element, etc..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Unfortunately I'm not at my work computer right now) but Cognos saves everything in .xml files.  I have an xml pretty printer that I use on model.xml before and after edits, so that I can use windiff to see what exactly changes in the model.  I have also used an xml editor on model.xml on several occasions for global search and replace.

Having said that, I'm not sure how much of the database schema you can infer directly from model.xml, but I suspect if you had a script that could read and walk model.xml, and connect to the database to describe the objects, you could get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be [yes, to anything that supports CWM](http://www.cognos.com/pdfs/issue_papers/ip_integration_with_c8bi.pdf) (the Common Warehouse Model) but as for *how*...

One suggestion: ask IBM.

Comment: Yeah, there's that.  Any chance of getting it from the other end (e.g. database logs)?  Though if you're using Cognos you're probably in an environment where it takes three weeks to find out how to contact the person responsible for managing the people who make sure there are towels in the bathroom.

Comment: I actually work with the dba.  I'm a programmer, but don't have access rights yet because of licensing issues.  We just started using it this week and I'm in training.  You can't search for a table.field name, cant see any ERDs, etc...  Me and another person are manually logging paths in excel YAY!

Comment: I feel your pain.  Or maybe I'm just having flashbacks.  Sad to say, you're probably doing it the most efficient way.  I'm assuming, of course, you've asked the dba for the design docs/schema?  Which brings up an interesting question: where do those docs go to?

Comment: From what i understand, you can export content out of the framework manager (regular users do not have access to this).  This might have to be my route, but I'd rather find a way to do it at the user level

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Powerdesigner 15 imports from xmi models.